# how to install pgsql_pdo?

Tags: postgresql, pecl, pdo

I need to install pgsql_pdo but getting this error via

root@server5 [~]# pecl install pdo_pgsql

```
root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:1139: error: â€˜zend_internal_functionâ€™ has no member named â€˜pass_rest_by_referenceâ€™
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:1140: error: â€˜zend_internal_functionâ€™ has no member named â€˜return_referenceâ€™
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c: In function â€˜pdo_dbh_initâ€™:
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:1242: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c: In function â€˜pdo_dbh_newâ€™:
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:1413: error: â€˜zend_class_entryâ€™ has no member named â€˜default_propertiesâ€™
make: *** [pdo_dbh.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
7 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
building in /root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootAz8UPA/PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2
running: /root/tmp/pear/PDO_PGSQL/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for PostgreSQL support for PDO... yes, shared
checking for pg_config... not found
configure: error: Cannot find libpq-fe.h. Please specify correct PostgreSQL installation path
ERROR: `/root/tmp/pear/PDO_PGSQL/configure' failed
```

Comment: Install `postgresql-dev`:  `$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.5` or    `$ sudo yum install postgresql-devel`

Answer (score 3):

Out of the long terminal session you posted, the only important piece is:

```
Cannot find libpq-fe.h
```

So use whatever tools your distro provides (you didn't say which distro you're using) to find the package that has that file.  Then install that package and try again.  It's probably named libpq-devel or similar.  For example in Debian-based distros, you can run

```
apt-file search libpq-fe.h
```

Comment: I am new to Linux and had never come across apt-file, solved my problem this time and I am sure it will help again in the future.